# Hide div when not active (link) Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, navigation, hide, slide

So here I am trying to have a cool navigation system with Jquery. Basicaly I got only one page and the content just slide when the links are being clicked. It works just fine, I used this little plugin that I adapted to my design. [jQuery Tab Slider](http://www.geoffreyrickaby.com/jQueryPlugins/Tab-Slider/)

The problem is, with this design, we actually can see the others divs when they are not 'active' (well, when the link isn't, you get it) You can see what it looks like in live [here](http://dissidence-belge.be/stack-overflow-test/)

My question: is there a way to easily hide the content other than the one related to the active link ? Without altering the slide effect.

Oh and if you have something else in mind that could be proper/easier, just let me know, I'm open to everything.

Comment: There is an error in your jQuery UI and sendChat.php is constantly pinging requests?

Comment: Thanks for noticing that mate. Even tho I don't really know where that can come from.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery Tab Slider uses:

- Main container, say 700px width with overflow:hidden
- Slider-wrapper (this width is computed, but no additional styling
- Slider-content, say ~700px with padding, floating left.

In your website this CSS does the trick:

```
.tab-main-content {
  width: 1089px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```